# How to assign object in array of objects?

Tags: angular

I have this:

```
values = [];
```

In ts i have multiple services that they have been called in different time.
I trie to add that values of objects in array, but that values can be changed and i dont want to add always them in array, i want to assign if the objects values has been changed.

```
 this.values = this.values.map(a=>) Object.assign(this.values, [{ title: 'E-mail', indicator: this.emailData.length }]);
this.values = this.values.map(a=>) Object.assign(this.values, [{ title: 'Assgnment', indicator: this.assignments.length }]);
```

and so on. But it always add one object and thats it.
ANy suggestion?

EDIT:

if i add this:

```
this.values.push(
  { title: 'E-mail', indicator: this.emailData.length }
)
```

If value has been changed i will have multiple objects with title:'E-mail', because it will always push in array new objects even if only indicator has been changed and i dont want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `push` for it, like this:

```
 loadValues(title: string, indicator: string) {
    let existingData = this.values.filter(x => x.title == title && x.indicator == indicator)
    if (existingData == null) {
      this.values.push(
        { title: title, indicator: indicator }
      )
    } else {
      let data = this.values.filter(x => x.title == title);

      for(var i=0; i< this.values.length;i++){
        if(this.values[i].title == data.title) {
          this.values[i].indicator = indicator
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes, and if value has been changed i will have multiple objects with title:'E-mail', because it will always push in array new objects even if only indiciator has been changed and i dont want that

Comment: Modified the answer, call this function, this will check if the same value exists

Comment: I dont think that u understand me... i want to change value in array for that same title if indicator has been changed... so if i have title:'Email' and it have indicator :1, next time if indicator is 2 for title:'Email' i want to changed that value in array and not to insert new one.